# PHP DateTime Class opening/closing tags

Tags: php, datetime, standards

I am following some tutorials and came across something i can't seem to wrap my head around. Been searching for the reasoning or meaning of it.

Just practicing with the DateTime class i came across this code and tried it out. The code won't give me output when i use.

```
<?php
```

it does give me output when i use.

```
<?=
```

I've read about this kind of notation in PHP and it's more a personal preference nowadays. Still advisable to use the standard open/close tags because of older PHP versions that are not viable at understanding the newer tags.

So my question in short is : How come the DateTime class at the echo statement only accepts `<?= ?>` this tag to show me some output.

```
<?php

$publishDate = '2014-08-24 09:14:00';

$localDateTime = new DateTime($publishDate, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

$utcDateTime = clone $localDateTime;

$utcDateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

?>

<p>The UTC date/time is: <?= $utcDateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") ?></p>
<p>The New York date/time is: <?= $localDateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") ?></p>"
```

Comment: `<?=` is a php short echo tag, equivalent to `<?php echo` : `<p>The UTC date/time is: <?php echo $utcDateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") ?></p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<?=` is a shorthand PHP `echo` statement, essentially meaning `<?php echo(...`

Note that this tag is **not** to be confused with the short open tag: `<?` - it is a completely different operator and, as of PHP 5.4, the "short echo tag" is actually not affected by the `short_open_tag` setting:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: Thank you! I've been staring to much at the screen also i think overlooking the echo maybe .This explains it well!.

Answer (score 1):

So `<?php` and `<?=` are two different things, the latter is a shorthand that also uses `echo` if you wanted to achieve the same thing with `<?php` you would do something like:

```
<?php 

$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Or in your example:

```
<p>The UTC date/time is: <?php echo $utcDateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") ?></p>
<p>The New York date/time is: <?php echo $localDateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") ?></p>"
```